# mongodb-rust-driver perform poorly on find and get large amount of data compare to go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, rust

I have a database consist of 85.4k of document with average size of 4kb

I write a simple code in go to find and get over 70k document from the database using [mongodb-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "log"
  "time"

  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
  localC, _ := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb"))
  localDb := localC.Database("sampleDB")
  collect := localDb.Collection("sampleCollect")

  localCursor, _ := collect.Find(context.TODO(), JSON{
    "deleted": false,
  })
  log.Println("start")
  start := time.Now()

  var result []map[string] interface{} = make([]map[string] interface{}, 0)

  localCursor.All(context.TODO(), &result)

  log.Println(len(result))
  log.Println("done")
  log.Println(time.Now().Sub(start))
}
```

Which done in around 20 seconds

```
2021/03/21 01:36:43 start
2021/03/21 01:36:56 70922
2021/03/21 01:36:56 done
2021/03/21 01:36:56 20.0242869s
```

After that, I try to implement the similar thing in rust using [mongodb-rust-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver#configuring-the-async-runtime)

```
use mongodb::{
  bson::{doc, Document},
  error::Error,
  options::FindOptions,
  Client,
};
use std::time::Instant;
use tokio::{self, stream::StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let client = Client::with_uri_str("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    .await
    .unwrap();
  let db = client.database("sampleDB");

  let coll = db.collection("sampleCollect");
  let find_options = FindOptions::builder().build();

  let cursor = coll
    .find(doc! {"deleted": false}, find_options)
    .await
    .unwrap();

  let start = Instant::now();
  println!("start");

  let results: Vec<Result<Document, Error>> = cursor.collect().await;
  let es = start.elapsed();
  println!("{}", results.iter().len());
  println!("{:?}", es);
}
```

But it took almost 1 minutes to complete the same task on release build

```
$ cargo run --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.43s
    Running `target\release\rust-mongo.exe`
start
70922
51.1356069s
```

May I know the performance on rust in this case is consider normal or I made some mistake on my rust code and it could be improve?

**EDIT**

As comment suggested, here is the [Example document](https://gist.github.com/LeeJiaLe/31b55499541d543177257e8c287f9916)

Comment: `var result []map[string] interface{} = make([]map[string] interface{}, 0)` this I don't understand. Anyway, the mongo driver in rust is official but still in beta, I guess this is expected. Also, your test could just show that mongo server was more slow at this moment, to have a real number you will need to subtract the time mongoDB process the request.

Comment: I was able to reproduce with smaller documents on a smaller dataset, the Rust version reports taking about twice as long. However, 80k documents about 4k big I got Go: 5.422489s and Rust: 5.8449128s. My sample documents were very basic though so the discrepancy may come down to deserialization performance of complex objects.

Comment: Agree on deserialization time, without the data set this question is not answerable.

Comment: I've add an example document, hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy here was due to some known bottlenecks in the Rust driver that have since been addressed in the latest beta release (2.0.0-beta.3); so, upgrading your `mongodb` dependency to use that version should solve the issue.

Re-running your examples with 10k copies of the provided sample document, I now see the Rust one taking ~3.75s and the Go one ~5.75s on my machine.